# MAMP Apache server suddenly stopped working - no errors in the logs

Tags: apache, macos, mamp

It worked fine and then it just stopped working. version 1.9.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably nothing trivial like closing the control panel and closing the MAMP server? There is a button/check box to keep the services running when the control panel is closed.

[edit] this is about setting up Symfony in MAMP but it runs through MAMP config. It an be pointed at the wrong php etc. THis is all for MAc so i am assuming that is what you are using but i think it is the same on Windows with minor variations. Hope it helps.
[Howto MAMP blog](http://www.adamstacey.co.uk/2010/06/28/installing-symfony-in-mamp-on-os-x/)

Comment: Don't use it on this machine, it's at work so i cannot look till monday. But when i open up the config panel and set up the apache and mysql etc. all the services run. however somewhere on that panel is a checkbox to keep he servers running when the panel is shut. However if you have restarted everything and it was running previously when you did that and now it doesn't then i would suspect something else. Have you changed any other configurations. have added a link in my answere have a run through that.